# For loop, waiting until external method has completed

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

I can't figure this out, I'm learning as I go. I have an array of cards that I want to move to a set location. This works fine except they all appear to move at once. I want a way to check if the first has finished moving before the second one does. Heres my code so far:

```
-(void)AIturn {  

int NuUnits = [p2Units count];
for (int q = 0; q < NuUnits; q++)
    {
    [self unselectUnit];
    selectedUnit = [p2Units objectAtIndex:q] ;
    CGPoint moveto = CGPointMake(184,556);
    TileData * td = [self getTileData:[self tileCoordForPosition:moveto]];
    //[selectedUnit doMarkedMovement:td ];
     [selectedUnit performSelector:@selector(doMarkedMovement:) withObject:td afterDelay:0.5];
   NSLog(@"%@ moved", selectedUnit);
    }
```

So, What Ideally I want is for it to know when doMarkedMovement has finished doing its stuff and then run through the loop again.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have doMarkedMovement send a notification when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `doMarkedMovement` call a method when it's done - let's call it `procNextMovement` - and `procNextMovement` calls `doMarkedMovement` on the next element in the list.

Alternatively, if this works it would be much simpler - change the `afterDelay` parameter. So if each `doMarkedMovement` takes 0.2 seconds to complete, then your `afterDelay`s will be: 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1, etc... This wouldn't be as precise as doing the callback method though.

Something like this:

```
- (void) AIturn {
    upTo = 0; //has to be an instance variable
    [self procNextTurn];
}

- (void) procNextTurn {
    if (upTo >= NuUnits) {
        //done
        return;
    }

    [self unselectUnit];
    selectedUnit = [p2Units objectAtIndex:upTo];
    CGPoint moveto = CGPointMake(184, 556);
    TileData * td = [self getTileData:[self tileCoordForPosition:moveto]];
    upTo += 1
    [selectedUnit performSelector:@selector(doMarkedMovement:) withObject:td afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

Then in the `selectedUnit`'s function:

```
- (void) doMarkedMovement:(id td) {
    //regular code here
    //callback once movement is done, where `caller` is whatever the object above was
    [caller procNextTurn];
}
```

Comment: changing the 'afterDelay' kinda works, but is clunky. The cards come from different places so they don't take the same time. I don't follow what you mean with your first suggestion. Sorry I'm still learning as I go. The for loop finishes it's entire run before 'DoMarkedMovement' finishes for the first one, so wouldn't calling another method that calls it again just restart the for loop at 0?

Comment: @user3166360: Ah I mean, drop the for loop. You're not taking `NuUnits` actions at once. You're taking one action, then another, then another, etc. I'll write in some code